# How can I get the list of OPC UA servers on .Net C#?

Tags: list, proxy, server, client, opc-ua

I'm writing a OPC proxy program in C#. I want to get the list of all OPC-Server on `localhost` or remote of the machine. I'm using OPC UA .NET from OPC foundation V1.26

I inspired me from the "sampleDiscovery-Programm" of Softing and I have now my list of servers as `ApplicationDescription`.

Now I want to see the connected client of a specified server. With the sample "servers_control-Programm" from Softing, I can see all client of a server. But the constructor of this class need servers as `StandardServer` and the `ApplicationConfiguration`

```
    public ServerForm(StandardServer server, ApplicationConfiguration configuration)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_server = server;

        m_configuration = configuration;
        this.ServerDiagnosticsCTRL.Initialize(m_server, m_configuration);

        TrayIcon.Text = this.Text = m_configuration.ApplicationName;
        this.Icon = TrayIcon.Icon = ConfigUtils.GetAppIcon();
    }
```

How can I use main servers as `ApplicationDescription` for a servers as StandardServer?

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Please include what you have and what issues you're facing

Comment: Why can i have a currentInstance from a server with type ApplicationDescription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPC Labs Quick OPC Calssic` to get the list od `OPC UA servers` list in `VB.NET`.

Download and install `QuickOPC 5.23(.NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0)` or `QuickOPC 5.31(.NET Framework 4.5)` from **http://opclabs.com/products/quickopc/downloads**

**VB.NET Code:**

```
' Instantiate the client object
 Dim easyUAClient = New EasyUAClient()
    
' Obtain collection of server elements
Dim applicationElementCollection As UAApplicationElementCollection = easyUAClient.DiscoverServers()
    
' Display results
For Each applicationElement As UAApplicationElement In applicationElementCollection
    Console.WriteLine("applicationElementCollection[""{0}""].ApplicationUriString: {1}", _
                                  applicationElement.DiscoveryUriString, applicationElement.ApplicationUriString)
Next applicationElement
```

[image]